# Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension SecureExecution flag not working

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation

We are running a custom powershell script against an Azure VM using the Set-AzureRMVMCustomScriptExtension command.

The ps script creates local user accounts provided with "username" and "password" parameters.

My understanding is that Set-AzureRMVMCustomScriptExtension supports -SecureExecution switch, which according to the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/set-azurermvmcustomscriptextension?view=azurermps-4.4.1&viewFallbackFrom=azurermps-4.4.0)

"Indicates that this cmdlet makes sure that the value of the Run parameter is not logged on the server or returned to the user by using the GET extension API. The value of Run might contain secrets or passwords to be passed to the script file securely."

However, providing the switch and executing the ps script results in the following being logged to the "Windows Powershell" event log on the target VM:

Engine state is changed from None to Available.

Details: 
    NewEngineState=Available
    PreviousEngineState=None

```
SequenceNumber=13

HostName=ConsoleHost
HostVersion=5.1.14393.1770
HostId=
HostApplication=powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file createuser.ps1 -username myNewUser -password somePassword
EngineVersion=5.1.14393.1770
RunspaceId=
PipelineId=
CommandName=
CommandType=
ScriptName=
CommandPath=
CommandLine=
```

Which is not what I am expecting to see. Is this a bug? Or is the documentation incorrect?

This is the command I'm executing:

Set-AzureRmVMCustomScriptExtension -ResourceGroupName $vmResourceGroupName 
    `-VMName $vmName`
    -StorageAccountName $scriptStorageAccountName 
    `-ContainerName $scriptStorageAccountContainerName`
    -FileName $scriptName 
    `-Run $scriptName`
    -Argument $scriptArguments 
    `-Name $extensionAlias`
    -Location $location 
    `-ForceRerun $(New-Guid).Guid`
    -SecureExecution

Answer (score 0):

Well, its not like Azure can magically change how windows server operates. this is windows server logging, not extension logging. it won't log this to the extension log and will hide sensitive information from the api, but, obviously, powershell engine can log this input like any other input